# Unable to access variable or pass variable to other functions

Tags: javascript, parameter-passing, var

Hi I'm pretty new to javascript and am having trouble with a function accessing another variable defined in another function. I've raised it to be global, but also have tried to return the desired variable to be accessed in another function.

Below is the code and what I am trying to do is have the var correctAnswer in the function SubmitUpdate() get passed the to function selectedvalue() in order to see if it is correct or not. Everything else is working as needed. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
function skipped() {
  state.skippedAnswers += 1;
  SubmitUpdate();
}

let state = {
  score: 0,
  wrongAnswers: 0,
  skippedAnswers: 0
}

var correctAnswer;

let myObj = [{}]

function totalQuestion() {
  var counterG = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < myObj.length; i++) {
    counterG++;
  }
  return counterG;
}

SubmitUpdate();

function SubmitUpdate() {
  var countNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 17);
  var key = myObj.find(x => x.id === 17);
  var test = key.A1;
  var question1 = key.question;
  var answer1 = key.A1;
  var answer2 = key.A2;
  var answer3 = key.A3;
  var correctAnswer = key.correctanswer;
  console.log(correctAnswer);
  document.getElementById("Question").innerHTML = question1;
  document.querySelector(".q1").innerHTML = answer1;
  document.getElementById("A1").value = answer1;
  document.querySelector(".q2").innerHTML = answer2;
  document.getElementById("A2").value = answer2;
  document.querySelector(".q3").innerHTML = answer3;
  document.getElementById("A3").value = answer3;
  return {
    correctAnswer
  }
}

function selectedvalue() {
  var ele = document.getElementsByName('questionName');
  for (i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) {
    if (ele[i].checked)
      var value = ele[i].value;
  }
  if (value === SubmitUpdate.correctAnswer) {
    state.score += 1;
  } else {
    state.wrongAnswers += 1;
  }
  console.log(state.score);
  console.log(correctAnswer);
}
```

Comment: Also I erased the myObj questions to save space, so it does have values and are being pulled, but unable to pass. Thank you.

Comment: If you declare a variable inside a function, that variable is not accesible outside of that function, you are re declaring the variable `correctAnswer` inside the `SubmitUpdate` that overwrites the global one

Comment: `SubmitUpdate.correctAnswer` is not how you access a variable declare inside a function, follow Ben`s suggestion and access the global variable

Answer (score 4):

By writing `var correctAnswer = key.correctanswer` inside `SubmitUpdate` you create a new local variable in the function, which takes priority over the global variable with the same name. To modify the global variable, write `correctAnswer = key.correctanswer`, without `var`.

Comment: Thank you Ben West!

Answer (score 0):

Line 50, try to call method SubmitUpdate instead of using it as an object.

```js
if (value === SubmitUpdate().correctAnswer) {
    state.score += 1;
}
```